# How to calculate $P(X^2 < X)$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I need help with this:

Let $X \sim \mathcal{exp(1)}$. we need to calculate $P(X^2 < X)$.

All I know so far $P(X^2<X) = P(-$$\sqrt{X}<$X$<$$\sqrt{X}$) = P($X$<$\sqrt{X}$)

whats now?

Comment: I made an edit. I you mean something different please make an edit of my edit.

Comment: how do I do sqrt func?? @callculus

Comment: $ \text{\$\sqrt{X}\$} $ gives $\sqrt{X}$.

Comment: **Hint:** $X^2<X$ if and only if $0<X<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the exponential distribution has support $[0,\infty)$. On this domain we have $X^2<X$ if and only if $X <1$. So $P(X^2<X) = P(X<1)$ From this you should be able to caclulate the probability.

Comment: I got 1-1/e?? thats right?

Comment: Yes that looks right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $X^2 < X$ if and only if $X(X-1)<0$. Can you figure out the rest?

**Hint 2:** Note that \begin{align*}
P(X^{2}<X) & =P(X(X-1)<0)\\
 & =P(X\leq0\text{ and }X-1\geq 0)+P(X\geq0\text{ and }X-1\leq 0)\\
 & =0+P(X\geq0\text{ and }X\leq 1)\\
 & =F_{X}(1)
\end{align*}
where $F_{X}$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

Comment: no, how can I do something with that?

Comment: I have added a more in-depth hint. I've essentially given away the answer.

Comment: ohh @flawr gave me a hint so I got Fx(1) and the answer is 1-1/e

Comment: Yes, our hints are essentially identical. Now that you have the answer, considering upvoting one or more of them and accepting one of them.

Answer (score 1):

$X^2<X$ if and only if $0<X<1$. Thus
$$P(X^2<X)=P(0<X<1)=\int_{0}^{1}{e^{-x}dx}=1-e^{-1}.$$